# Finding in Mongoose with specific parametres

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database in Mongodb filled with profiles with different skills.

Here's an example of one profile.

```
{_id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a837,
  identifier: 'Mr X',
  url: 'https://MRX.com',
  email: 'Mrx@gmail.com'
skills: 
   [ { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a858, title: 'Java', number: '74' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a857, title: 'Linux', number: '48' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a856, title: 'C++', number: '43' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a855, title: 'SQL', number: '34' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a854, title: 'XML', number: '28' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a853, title: 'MySQL', number: '23' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a852, title: 'C', number: '22' },
     { _id: 570b8b5afdcaf27c24a0a851,
       title: 'Java Enterprise Edition',
       number: '18' }]
}
```

My question: is there a query in mongoose where I can find a profile who has linux in his skills but also the number of that linux skill is greater than 40?

I tried with something like this in the finding option :

```
var x = {
    'skills.title': 'Linux',
    'skills.number': {
        $gt: 40
    },
}
```

but it doesn't work,the program finds the Linux skill but number 40 is not associated with Linux.

So is there a query to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.yourCollection.find(
   { skills: { $elemMatch: { title: "Linux", number: { $gte: 40 } } } }
)
```

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

Comment: It seems to work when I put the number as equal to 40 but when I want it to be greater than 40, I get  all the profiles  equal or greater or less than 40.
Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Make sure your `number` is a number and not a string (no quotes)

Answer (score -2):

In mongoose you should do something like this:

```
var myCol = require('.myModel');
myCol.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: 
            { 
                title: "Linux", 
                number: { $gte: 40 } 
            }
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```